# How to achieve this text effect in Adobe Illustrator?‎

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, illustrator-effects

I’m a beginner with **Adobe Illustrator** and try to get the screenshot text effect, but I ‎couldn’t able to do it. I try “**Warp**” submenu effects (**Effects** > **Warp**), but didn’t ‎work for me. Does this possible in Adobe Illustrator or it needs **Adobe Photoshop** ‎to reach it? My Adobe Illustrator is the last version. The below section of this ‎effect (“*experience*” words) seems easier to create, but I would be surprised; how ‎the upper part (wave effect to “*life*” words and blend-like effect, and how morphs from ‎‎“*experience*” words to “*life*” words) create and give effect to its. ‎
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a job for Object > Envelope distort > Mesh
I don't have time to make a complete tutorial but you might have to watch a few videos or read articles in order to understand how distorting envelope with a mesh works.
I suggest you dig into it and come back for feedback/help.

Here's a quick and (very) rough try, still not too far from what you want:

[image]

Comment: Thank You @Vinny, it worked! I tried "Envelope with Mesh" feature. My result not exact as my screenshot example and almost become ugly! but it's a good try for the first time I use it and as you said I need to watch and read tutorials more to become better in this great option!